# Generate HTML with plotly graphs and a navbar

Tags: python, html, graph, plotly

I am running a Python pipeline that generates some data files. As a last step of the pipeline, I want to generate a HTML file containing nicely styled graphs representing that data with plotly and a navbar at the top (I will probably have 2 tabs, each one containing different set of charts). This sounds like hard to do with plotly only. How can I achieve this? Should I make an html file with some styling, then just embed the plotly graphs in it? Or should I try to do it solely using plotly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some something similar writing the html (and nav elements) from python and then embedding the charts using the `to_html` method:

```
fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! :) How do you embed the html generated into a separate html file at specific position? :)

Comment: You can do something like '<html> ...... {fig} .... </html>'.format(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True))